# Chrome Dev Tools Performance Tab - Profiling

Tags: performance, google-chrome, profiling, devtools, timeline

When attempting to profile a webpage using Chromes Dev tools, since the most recent update most performance profiles load something like the attached image.  All the data is crammed up against the right side of the timeline and now there are negative milliseconds included in the timeline... which doesnt make sense.  Is anyone else having this issue since the most recent chrome update?  I cant find anything in google docs.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use the 'Record' and 'Start Profiling and reload page' buttons on the performance tab a lot and also have the bug similar to yours on Windows platform since Chrome v.90 (Chrome v.92 also have this bug), Linux versions are not affected.

As a temporary solution, you can downgrade Chrome to any version below 90 (configure your system to prevent Chrome updates): [Chrome x64 v.86](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/download-chrome.php?file=files%2F86.0.4240.75%2FChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe) ([other versions/platforms](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php))

If you need to use the latest Chrome version, you can install an older Opera or Opera GX (e.g., LVL2 ver.68) to use it with non-bugged performance tab (newer Opera versions also have this bug because they also have an updated Chromium engine)